# Twilio: pass parameter between bins

Tags: twilio

I am using Twilio to establish a phone call between two persons.

I use Twilio C# API to call the first person from my number and to invoke a TwiML bin that says a welcome message and dials a call to the second person.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>{{Welcome}}</Say>    
    <Dial>{{Dial}}</Dial>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

This TwinML bin works fine.

Now, I need to change the requirement: I want to loop the welcome message and wait for the person to press a button before calling the second person.

For this I put in place two TwiML bins: the first bin waits for the user input and triggers an action to the second bin to make the call.
When I invoke the first bin, I pass the `{{Welcome}}` message and the number to `{{Dial}}` in order to call the second person.
So I would like to pass the `{{Dial}}` parameter to the second bin.

I tried to pass it as a querystring parameter but when the action is invoked, it fails: a voice says that an error occured.

First bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather numDigits="1" timeout="60" action="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/123456789123456?Dial={{Dial}}">
        <Say loop="0">{{Welcome}}</Say>    
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

Second bin (https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/123456789123456):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>{{Dial}}</Dial>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

How can I achieve to pass url parameters from the TwiML template?

Thanks

Comment: If you got an error on the call, then there is likely a message in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger). Take a look there and see what it says.

Comment: ok thank you, the debugger hepled, it pointed us to an encoding problem of the parameter.

Comment: Glad to hear it!